# Cannot send request for more than once with Serversocket in Java

Tags: java, request, client-server

I have a simple Client-Server App in Netbeans that send login request to server and listen to the answer from server.

I declare these codes in the constructor of Client:

```
    try {
        socket = new Socket("localhost", 12345);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And the request sender when click the button with `str` is the info of the login:

```
public void request_login(String str) {
    try {

        this.oos.writeInt(1);
        this.oos.writeUTF(str);
        this.oos.flush();
        System.out.println("CLIENT: Sent!");

        int responseCode = this.ois.readInt();
        if (responseCode == Protocol.OK) {
            //OK handler
        }else {
        //Fail handler
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException ee) {
                ee.printStackTrace();
            }

}
```

And this is my Server:

```
public ServerATM() {
    try {
                this.serversocket = new ServerSocket(12345);
                System.out.println("Server is listening!");

                for(;;){
                        Socket socket = this.serversocket.accept();
                        Thread t = new ClientThread(socket);
                        t.start();
                }
        } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

And the `ClientThread` class:

```
  public ClientThread(Socket socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
    try {
                this.ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                this.oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

private void processThread() {
    try {
        int requestCode = this.ois.readInt();
        switch(requestCode) {
            case 1:
                String request = ois.ReadUTF();
                // Handle the code with the request.
                //Then return the result for client
                oos.writeInt(5);
                oos.flush();
                break;
            case 2:
                break;
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ClientThread.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}

public void run(){
    processThread();
}
```

The code works fine for the first click. But when I change the input string and click again the code just hangs. The `processThread` only called once at the first click, the second click does not call it so it won't do my codes.

Looks like when a request is sent, it create a new thread in Server, but in this case it's already created so it won't run again. Is there anyway I can send request for many times and the Server will listen them all?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call `processThread()` method in method `run()` in `ClientThread` using a while loop.

```
public void run(){
    while(true) processThread();
}
```

Hope this will help..